# Using pandas DataFrame.eval function to alter subset of rows inplace

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I know this works in pandas (df is a dataframe, op is a column, mult is a float variable):

```
df.eval("op = op * @mult", inplace=True)
```

But is it possible to do it on a subset of rows (in place)?  This gives me an error (ex_date is a local variable of type timestamp, and the index of df is a timestamp):

```
df.eval("df.loc[df.index < @ex_date, op] = op * @mult", inplace=True)
```

Error is:
*SyntaxError: left hand side of an assignment must be a single name*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not currently possible to do a conditional eval in place.  There is an outstanding feature request for this.  The proposed syntax would have your example looking something like:

```
df.eval("op = op * @mult if index < @ex_date else op", inplace=True)
```

([SOURCE](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/12945))

Comment: Thanks, I definitely am in favor of this change, as it allows eval() a hugely increased range of use cases--and eval() is much faster on large dataframes.  The proposed syntax seems fine (as long as its performance is as good as or better than alternatives).